# (angularjs ui grid)how to add an ng-click on the headercellclass?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

[I want an event in this name whenever I click It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx0Bs.png)
I mean i'm in typescript angularjs.
I'm using angular Ui-Grid.

i want to make my header cell, clickable

is there a ways to insert an onclick event on the headercell of ui grid

I don't want to redesign the template 
I just want to add click event in the headercell

Comment: Share your code, also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) otherwise you wont get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
<div ng-class="{ 'text-success': clicked, 'text-large': !clicked }">
```

on controller

```
$scope.setClass(new function(){
    $scope.clicked = true;
})
```

Comment: <div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
where in this should i put that ?

Comment: <div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ng-click="setClass()">

Comment: if I do that then everytime I click the grid, it will activate,
what i want is the headercellclass only